# ASP.NET increase & decrease date by clicking image

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, webforms

I want to increase & decrease date on Image click like this. '<' for decrease and '>' for increment and show them in textbox. I tried like following code but not working
kindly help me to do so

```
protected void ImageButtonNextDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{                        
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime nextday = date.AddDays(1);

    txtDate.Text = nextday.ToShortDateString();
}

protected void ImageButtonPrevDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime nextday = date.AddDays(-1);

    txtDate.Text = nextday.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Can you pub a break point into code and get there.  Not sure if buttons are working properly or some other issue.

Comment: Please tell us, what exactly is not working. Are the dates the same every time you click the button? Do they change however not in the way you need? Do you catch an exception?

Comment: @Taosique Today is 2016-03-06 right? When I click it Changes to 2016-03-07 so far so good but if I click again it stay on 2016-03-07. What I want is at evry click to add one day.  click 2016-03-07, click 2016-03-08 , click 2016-03-09 ........ Every time I handle click event on my image want to add one day.

Comment: That's because every time you create a new date variable your program is unaware of and assign it with current date + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you handle click event on your images, you create a new `date` variable with value equal to current date. You need to store data between clicks somehow, so that it's retained for the next event. There are multiple ways to do so, for example, session variables:

```
protected void ImageButtonPrevDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = Session["MyDateVariable"] as DateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
    DateTime nextday = date.AddDays(-1);
    Session["MyDateVariable"] = nextday;
    txtDate.Text = nextday.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I'am not so expert with session .. is there any other way to solv? Thank you again.

Comment: Well, your approach is wrong from the start - there's really no need to do the postback to server every time user clicks an image just to change the value. It can be handled purely client-side with JavaScript. TL/DR: just take the Session code and you'll be fine.

Comment: Can you pls show me how to code it in Java. I tried in one hour and cant get it... tried with onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;' value='+'/ but nothing happen. I realy I'am not java person....and don't know how to code and where my txtDate.Text  coming in Picture with Java. Thank you  again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the current value from the `txtDate`, then perform the logic.

```
protected void ImageButtonNextDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Text = (Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).AddDays(1)).ToShortDateString();                   
}
protected void ImageButtonPrevDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Text = (Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).AddDays(-1)).ToShortDateString();          
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You only need to load the value of `DateTime.Now` to `txtDate` on first page load, on every post back, do not set it.

```
if(!IsPostBack()){
   txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response .. But I have the same problem as my code. It adds only the first click. When I click next click then it stay with the same day. I want every time I click then the day increase or decrease.

Comment: Today is 2016-03-06 right? When I click it Changes to 2016-03-07 so far so good but if I click again it stay on 2016-03-07. What I want is at evry click to add one day. click 2016-03-07, click 2016-03-08 , click 2016-03-09 ........ Every time I handle click event on my image want to add one day.

Comment: @JonasWillander: did you set txtDate.Text on every post back?

Comment: Yes I did but nothing happen. Thanks again.